# Get both unsrtnat and APA style using natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

Is there a way to get both `unsrtnat` and `apa` style at the same time while using `natbib`? I would like to have the references displayed the way they get displayed using `unsrtnat` but just in APA style.

Comment: Can you make your edit into an answer in the answer field below? That way we can give you a bit more points and your question has a nice answer.

Comment: Thought about posting it as an answer but wasn't sure. Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this issue myself by modifying the `unsrnat.bst` file. I mixed it up with code snippets from the `apa-ben.bst` and `apalike.bst` file, and fixed some whitespace issues regarding `urls` within the reference list. I uploaded it on github in case anybody else might need such a bibliography style: https://goo.gl/UY6NQV.

[image: Mix of unsrtnat and APA style]