# Is there a way to show the "reference number in brackets" instead of "name, year"?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apacite

I'm using `apacite` package. and I was wondering whether there is a way to do this:

Let reference [5] be: "Besterfield, D. (2013). Quality improevment (9 ed.). Pearson."

When I use `\cite{Besterfield}`, latex prints `(Besterfield, 2013)`.
But what I need is `[5]` instead of `(Besterfield, 2013)`

Is there a way to get that `[5]`?

Comment: Yes, numbered citations are a common option for citation packages, normally set up by the choice of .bst style. Do you need to use `apacite`?  If not, [natbib](https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) is a flexible package for controlling citations.

Comment: I tried "\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}" but my issue is reversed, I get the "[5]" after using "\citenum{Besterfield}", but the references are not enumerated, i.e., every number in brackets next to a reference is removed.

Comment: Crosspost: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=32443

Comment: Perhaps try the `natbib` package instead, e.g. `\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}` with something like `\bibstyle{unsrtnat}`.  Or see the ideas in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322089/get-both-unsrtnat-and-apa-style-using-natbib)

Comment: Thank you all. I Solved my issue by editing my .bbl file, similar to what was suggested in the post showed by John.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comment.